# Run two scripts after each other in the background? && and & don't work?

Tags: zsh, background-process

I want to run two shell scripts after each other, in the background, preferably also using `nohup`.

I start with

```
% nohup a.sh &
```

This runs `a` in the background.

```
% nohup a.sh && nohup b.sh
```

This runs `a` and then `b` (if `a` succeeds)

But how do I launch the last combination in the background?

If I do

```
% nohup a.sh && nohup b.sh &
```

`a` will run in the foreground, blocking the prompt, and then `b` will be launched in the background, returning control to the prompt.

```
% nohup a.sh & && nohup b.sh &
```

This gives an error: `zsh: parse error near '&&'`

How do I launch two processes in the background?

Comment: Do you want the two scripts to run in parallel in the background, or does `b.sh` need to wait for `a.sh` to finish?

Comment: Not parallel. B depends on the output from A.

Comment: `nohup` is pointless in any job control shell (including zsh, bash, ksh, csh).

Comment: @chicks Is it? If I ssh to a computer, starts a script and the ssh connection is interrupted while the script is still running, the script is "killed", isn't it? nohup prevents that?

Comment: That's funny because my script isn't killed.  I reverify this every few years because it seems to be such a surprise.  Job control shells don't kill background jobs by default.

Answer (score 27):

That's one of the known deviations¹ of zsh compared to sh (or csh for that matters).

In sh:

```
A && B &
```

is short for:

```
(A && B) &
```

That is, it runs a subshell that runs that and-or list in background / asynchronously.

In zsh,

```
A && B &
```

Runs `A` synchronously, waits for it, and if successful, runs `B` in background / asynchronously.

That's [noted in its manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-list) (see `info zsh list`):

> A *list* is a sequence of zero or more sublists, in which each sublist
> is terminated by `;`, `&`, `&|`, `&!`, or a newline.  This terminator
> may optionally be omitted from the last sublist in the list when the
> list appears as a complex command inside `(...)` or `{...}`.  When a
> sublist is terminated by `;` or newline, the shell waits for it to
> finish before executing the next sublist.  **If a sublist is terminated by
> a `&`, `&|`, or `&!`, the shell executes the last pipeline in it in the
> background, and does not wait for it to finish (note the difference from
> other shells which execute the whole sublist in the background)**.  A
> backgrounded pipeline returns a status of zero.

(emphasis mine).

And [in the FAQ](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq02.html):

> In `cmd1 && cmd2 &`, only `cmd2` instead of the whole expression is run in the background in zsh. The manual implies this is a bug. Use `{ cmd1 && cmd2 } &` as a workaround.

To run a subshell that does `A && B` in background like in other shells, use:

```
(A && B) &
```

Or as suggested by that FAQ entry:

```
{A && B} &
```

Which are equivalent since we need to fork a process anyway if it has to run asynchronously (and the main shell process to carry on with the rest of the script at the same time).

So here:

```
(nohup a.sh && nohup b.sh) &
```

Though if you just want the process running that subshell and the other processes it spawns to be immune to the SIGHUP signal:

```
(trap '' HUP; A && B) &
```

(you can also add some `< /dev/null >> nohup.out 2>&1` to even more closely mimic nohup)

Conversely, if you want the same behaviour as zsh's in other sh-like shells:

```
A && { B & }
```

(bearing in mind that [in shells other than zsh, when job control is no enabled, the stdin of lists run asynchronously is redirected to /dev/null](/q/760852))

---

<sup>¹ It's possible that deviation may have been unintentional as the wording of the documentation before [that 2000 change to fix it to align with the actual behaviour](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/ed8b82b9b1bf74392caf4f4683f367bc4cbbd193#diff-6a204419ff23048734de2793d1072ec031dcdcd08aeb14cf75c14ec953835bddL68) (and that goes back all the way to zsh 1.0 in 1990) described the sh behaviour. That's also the conclusion of the FAQ that has had that *"The manual implies this is a bug"* [since 1997](https://www.usenetarchives.com/view.php?id=comp.unix.shell&mid=R0ZRUHprNFNsdmM). But it would be too late to change it now (but one would argue it should be changed in sh, csh or ksh emulations).</sup>

Answer (score 8):

You have to group the two commands together:

```
nohup sh -c 'a.sh; b.sh' &
```

Replace `;` with `&&` if you want `b.sh` to run only if `a.sh` exits with success