# Add a process to an already executing process? Like && or so

Tags: shell, zsh, macos, job-control

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761128/run-two-scripts-after-each-other-in-the-background-and-dont-work/) inspired me to another related question. Imagine that you start

```
% nohup a.sh &
```

and then want `b.sh` to execute when `a.sh` is finished (E.g., `b.sh` will process the output from `a.sh`. Both `a.sh` and `b.sh` are long running processes that takes hours to finish.)

Basically you want to simulate

```
% nohup a.sh && b.sh
```

but you forgot to add `b.sh` when you launched `a.sh`. Can this be achieved? Preferably in zsh.

Comment: Note that `A && B` is not *run B after A is finished*, it's *run B after A is finished and only if A was successful (exited with a 0 exit status)*. To run B after A, it's just `A; B` or A and B on separate lines.

Answer (score 3):

If the shell that started the process still knows about it (try `jobs`), then the shell built in `wait` can wait for it to finish. Something like this might work:

```
$ jobs
[1] nohup a.sh
$ wait -f %1 && nohup b.sh &
```

If you have lost the association in the shell then the `pidwait` command might work in a similar way, although it probably can't capture the exit value of the first process, and may run the second one even fi the first fails, unlike what `&&` does.

Comment: zsh's `wait` has no `-f` option. There's a `-f` in the `wait` builtin of bash, but that code wouldn't work in bash as `wait` there would be run in a subshell in background so wouldn't be able to wait for a.sh which wouldn't be its child.

Comment: Excellent. I don't have pidwait, does MacOS have something similar? Or is it a shell function?

Answer (score 3):

Only the parent process (or the child subreaper if any or `init` if the parent died), can retrieve the exit status of a process.

From the shell where you started the command, you can wait for it, and start `b.sh` in background if `a.sh` was successful with:

```
wait $pid && nohup b.sh &
```

In zsh or:

```
wait -f "$pid" && { nohup b.sh & }
```

In recent versions of bash (the `-f` for `wait` not to return when the process is only stopped; that's the default behaviour in `zsh`).

However the `wait` has to run in foreground. If run in background it would be in a child shell process and therefore would no longer be the parent of the process running `nohup a.sh`.

To retrieve the exit status of a process that is not your child one approach is to use a debugger and intercept the `_exit()`, `exit_group()` or equivalent system calls.

For instance, on Linux, one could do:

```
ret=$(strace -qqqa0 -e signal=none -e exit_group -p "$pid" 2>&1 | grep -Po '\(\K\d+')
```

The macos equivalent would likely involve a `truss` or `dtrace` command, but I don't have a machine to test that on.